# DatePickerDialog "month" keeps starting on 0 (Xamarin Android C#)

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, datepicker

I used DatePickerDialog in a fragment. I have a Button and an unclickable EditText. Whenever the user presses the button, it shows the DatePickerDialog, but the problem is when it chooses January, the value of the month is 0.

This is my code

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this.Activity, this, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.Show();


this.year = year;
this.month = month + 1;
this.day = dayOfMonth;
eventdatesetText.EditText.Text = month + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year;
```

Is my code right? Do I need to add something more on this code?

```
this.month = month + 1;
```

I have added + 1 but for some reason it is not working. Any solution? Thank you for future answers! I appreciate it a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you use `this.month = month + 1;`, so the code should be `eventdatesetText.EditText.Text = this.month + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year;`.

Or you can try to use `eventdatesetText.EditText.Text = (month+1) + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year;`.

In addition, you can try to custom a DatePickerDialog to show the month value. You can check my answer [in the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74463026/setformatter-method-implementation-for-convert-number-to-string-in-xamarin-andro/74472006#74472006).

Comment: Thank you! All I need was to use this.month instead!

Answer (score 0):

In the line that contains `eventdatesetText.EditText.Text =`, you should be using `this.month` instead of `month`.

As per your code, `month` is the 0-indexed month number, and you made `this.month` into the 1-indexed month number by doing a simple `+1` on it.

Since you want to use the 1-indexed month number, you should be using `this.month`.

Adjusted:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this.Activity, this, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.Show();


this.year = year;
this.month = month + 1;
this.day = dayOfMonth;
eventdatesetText.EditText.Text = this.month + "/" + this.day + "/" + this.year;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried upgrading to dotNet MAUI? I think this should be different there!

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2022 right now, how does that work? Thank you for the reply.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).